Why is a function that only returns a stateful lambda compiled down to any assembly at all?
The following non-templated (or is it?) function returning a non-generic, stateful lambda,
auto foo(double a) {
    return [a](double b) -> double {
        return a + b;
    };
}

compiled down to this with GCC or Clang. Why?
foo(double):
        ret

I would expect it generates no output at all.

The origin of the question
I don't even remember why I started writing the snippet above, but anyway...
Initially I thought it should have compiled to something slightly longer, as I was expecting to see an add instruction at least.
But then I realized that the foo above, cannot be just compiled alone, in a cpp, and then linked against another TU where it's used, because I can't even write a declaration-only for it!
So I get to the point that the only reason to write that function in a non-header file, is that it is used in that non-header file, at which point there's the compiler that can presumably inline it wherever it's used.
But if that's the case, then why compiling foo down to anything, if it's the only thing in the TU? There's nothing to link against, so why is any output generated at all for it?

Using a struct+operator() doesn't change anything, as this
struct Bar {
    double a;
    double operator()(double b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
};

Bar bar(double a) {
    return Bar{a};
}

generates the same ret-only code, which is also obvious in hindsight, as there's no way to even link against this bar function from other TUs, if Bar is hidden in the cpp file.

Could you please try to create a [mre] to show us, and copy-paste the actual assembly for that example into your question? And perhaps a link to the compiler explorer? Oh, and you do remember to build with optimization enabled?

@RichardCritten, fair enough about static, but even if it isn't, that foo can't possibly be used outside of this TU because you can't possibly write a declaration for other TUs to know about it. So what purpose does the foo(double): ret assembly serve?

@Someprogrammerdude: Of course this is with optimization enabled, otherwise GCC would set up a frame pointer and then tear down the stack frame.  As the OP said, they're talking about putting that code in a TU by itself, and expecting the compiler to realize that nothing could declare a prototype for this call and thus treat like it had the inline linkage specifier, not emitting a stand-alone definition in a compilation unit that didn't use one.

"there's no way to even link against this bar function from other TUs, if Bar is hidden in the cpp file." - Not true, a different TU could just contain a token-identical definition of Bar and a prototype for bar.

And even if not, the compiler lives in the real world, where someone could be insane enough to write a raw FFI-based declaration of foo in some different language (even assembly) and expect the linker to resolve it. So something must be there if the function has external linkage.

@SebastianRedl: Yes, calling from hand-written asm is a good argument.  Of course, that's not actually useful in this case, all the real information about the return value is its type; as you can see the function doesn't do anything, the only "return value" is double a that's still in XMM0 since we're looking at x86-64.  (Oh interesting, it actually is actively returning a, e.g. with gcc -m32 it loads a from the stack and stores it into memory pointed-to by an implicit first arg, like with large retvals that don't fit in a reg even though this would: https://godbolt.org/z/f66c3oY95)

@SebastianRedl: And yeah, duplicating just the definition of struct Bar should make calls from other TUs possible without seeing a definition for the function itself, but that only covers the last section, not the simpler case in the first code block.

Oh right, the return-value object isn't just a double, it's a lambda with space for captures, so I guess what's happening is returning a as part of that.  For the x86-64 System V ABI, a can apparently stay in XMM0 even if it's part of a larger object (probably up to 16 bytes). For i386 SysV, it can't.

Looks like a missed optimization that GCC and Clang presumably don't try to look for.  They'd have to run an extra optimization pass looking for functions that return lambdas like this and treat them as inline so they could avoid emitting a stand-alone definition in TUs that don't need one.
But if they did that, they'd fail to detect violations of the one-definition rule at link time.
e.g. ill-formed program if another TU contained int foo(double a){ return a; }
So that's a good reason not to treat it as inline and emit no asm.
But I guess they could emit just a .global foo ; foo: to define the symbol for ODR violation detection, without spending any code-size on a ret.  That would be a special case of generating asm, and likely not worth the extra code in the GCC or Clang internals to keep track of this special handling it should get, and to do it.
The value of such an optimization would be very minimal since as you say, this is just dead code in a real program where this function is in a TU with nothing that calls it.  It would cost compile time to look for it, and be code that GCC / Clang devs have to maintain.

But foo (as at the top of my question) was written in a cpp file, and a foo with the same signature but different body (say with - instead of +) was written in another cpp, and those TUs where linked together, why would the ODR be violated, if the two foos where independently treated as they need not be in the assembly of each TU? What I'm asking is, what would be wrong if the compiler interpreted a function like foo as implicilty inside a namespace /* unnamed */ {}?

@Enlico: Two global (non-static) definitions of functions with the same name and args is an error even if they're in separate TUs.  If you try to link a program that defines another foo(double) function (with the same or different return type), you want the compiler to notice and tell you about it.  What is the One-Definition Rule? - it puts requirements on definitions across separate TUs as well as within the same TU.

For any definable item D with definitions in multiple translation units, if D is a non-inline non-templated function or variable (or other bullet points, but the first one is relevant here) - the program is ill-formed.  So that might actually require a diagnostic.

I guess I'm implying that the ODR means that it's an error to put the linker in the condition of not knowing what to pick between multiple definitons, so you, as a programmer, ensure that your program obeys the ODR. But the foo in my question can't even possibly be declared in another TU, so how is it ever gonna conflict even with a copy of it? --- Ok, now I see. That very TU that contains this non-exposable foo could call foo and be linked with another TU that exposes another foo which just differs by return type, and the linker would not know which one I mean to call.

@Enlico: Yeah, your program is ill-formed if another TU contains an exact copy of that definition, or double foo(double a){ return 123; } or whatever.  It doesn't have to be possible to make calls to either of them, their mere existence is a problem.  AFAICT from the standard (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#15.1), a diagnostic is not required in this case. But GCC and Clang aim to give useful warnings and error messages in many cases when that's possible, as a quality-of-implementation / user-friendliness issue.  And not optimizing away is an easy way to get that.

Your suggestion of "emit a label and no instructions" is what gcc and clang both already do in case of a function whose body contains guaranteed UB, so that a correct program can't call the function at all.  https://godbolt.org/z/ETWhE71Wj.  So they could do the same in this case.  This optimization is controversial because it can lead to two functions having the same address, which the language isn't supposed to allow.  I guess it wouldn't be a problem in the case at hand because, if I understand correctly, foo not only can't be called, it can't even be referenced.

@NateEldredge: I thought about mentioning that, but thought there might be some downside to marking a function as having UB when it's actually totally fine.  e.g. in terms of future warnings, or something else we haven't thought of.  Since this optimization pass could only run after compiling every function in the TU since we need to identify any possible callers, there's no risk of breaking a function that actually is called.
